# Updating the state of a third-party object

Tags: reactjs, mxgraph

I am a beginner at React and I might be doing all of this wrong, but how do I update the state of a third-party object that has its own functions/variables?

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { mxGraph, mxRubberband, mxCell, mxGeometry, mxGraphHandler, mxEdgeHandler, mxParallelEdgeLayout, mxLayoutManager } from 'mxgraph-js';

class Graph extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {graph: new mxGraph(this.refs.graph)};
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let graph = this.state.graph;
    new mxRubberband(graph);

    let parent = graph.getDefaultParent();
    graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
    try {
      let v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, 'Hello world!', 20, 20, 80, 30);
    } finally {
      graph.getModel().endUpdate();
    }
    this.setState({graph});
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref="graph" className="graph"/>
  }
}

export default Graph;
```

The graph loads up onto the screen but the graph.insertVertex does not do anything. Please correct me if any of my practices are wrong.

Comment: `this.state = {graph: new mxGraph(this.refs.graph)};` in your constructor looks like a potential problem. Is `this.refs.graph` defined when your constructor is called?

Comment: @DacreDenny since the div is created in the render() method, no it is not. I am not sure where to initialize it if not in the constructor though. Can I declare an empty variable in the constructor to be later initialized in the componentDidMount method?

Comment: @DacreDenny Okay so I changed the constructor method to `this.state = {graph: new mxGraph()};` and re-initialized it within the componentDidMount method `graph = new mxGraph(this.refs.graph);`. This works now and shows the vertex within the graph, I am just not sure if this is the proper way to do so..

Comment: The initialization in the constructor is redundant. You should be able to remove `this.state = {graph: new mxGraph()};` in the constructor outright

Answer (score 0):

Does this resolve your issue?

Update your constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props); // You don't need to do any work here
}
```

Remove this, as there is no need to override the components update behaviour:

```
shouldComponentUpdate() {
  return false;
}
```

Update your `componentDidMount` method:

```
componentDidMount() {

this.setState({ graph: new mxGraph(this.refs.graph) }, () => {

    // This callback is invoked after the state has been set. It is now safe to access the graph field on state.

    let graph = this.state.graph;
    new mxRubberband(graph);

    let parent = graph.getDefaultParent();
    graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
    try {
          let v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, 'Hello world!', 20, 20, 80, 30);
    } finally {
          graph.getModel().endUpdate();
    }
    }));
}
```

Comment: Check my comment above, but this also works and I will be using the way you did it here rather than mine. Since graph was declared and initialized within the `componentDidMount()`, is the state still accessible through props if I were to pass it down to another component?

Comment: I don't believe so, so if you intend to use this component in that way, the component would need to be refactored a bit. In short, the reason we initalize the `mxGraph` in `componentDidMount` is because, at this stage in the `Graph` components life cycle, ref's are defined (ie refs.graph), meaning that you can safely attach a third part library to the underlying DOM. Because `this.state.graph` is not defined until the component has mounted, you would need to account for this if you were planning on passing the `graph` down to child components of `Graph` - hope that all makes sense

Comment: Makes sense as the lifecycle goes: `constructor() -> static getDerivedStateFromProps() -> render() -> componentDidMount()`. Do you think storing the state within a reducer with Redux would be the solution to be able to access the graph state within other components?

Comment: You got it - there's a great resource here if you'd like to learn more:
https://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/
See the sub heading: Initialization

Comment: Awesome, ill take a look at that and begin my research. I am not sure to accept your answer as my problem is bigger than the question I asked, but I will definitely upvote it as it helped me get in the right direction. Thanks for your help!